# Looping thru XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this Input XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn-sample">
  <CustomerRecord>
    <Statement>
      <StmtId>123</StmtId>
      <StmtDate>2013-08-16</StmtDate>
      <AcctNumber>123456789</AcctNumber>
      <Balance>
        <Type>OP</Type>
        <Amount>1.00</Amount>
        <CreditOrDebit>DR</CreditOrDebit>
        <Date>2013-08-15</Date>
      </Balance>
      <Balance>
        <Type>CL</Type>
        <Amount>2.00</Amount>
        <CreditOrDebit>CR</CreditOrDebit>
        <Date>2013-08-16</Date>
      </Balance>
      <Balance>
        <Type>FW</Type>
        <Amount>3.00</Amount>
        <CreditOrDebit>CR</CreditOrDebit>
        <Date>2013-08-17</Date>
      </Balance>
      <Entry>
        <Amount>7778.70</Amount>
        <CreditOrDebit>DR</CreditOrDebit>
        <EntryDtls>
          <TransactionDetails>
            <Parties>
              <Customer>
                <Name>Customer 1 Name</Name>
                <Address>Address Line 1</Address>
              </Customer>
              <CustomerAcct>
                <AcctName>Account Name 1</AcctName>
                <AcctNumber>12345677</AcctNumber>
              </CustomerAcct>
            </Parties>
            <AddlInfo>
              <Info1>Info 1</Info1>
              <Info1>Info 2</Info1>
              <Info1>Info 3</Info1>
            </AddlInfo>
          </TransactionDetails>
        </EntryDtls>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <Amount>5555.70</Amount>
        <CreditOrDebit>DR</CreditOrDebit>
        <EntryDtls>
          <TransactionDetails>
            <Parties>
              <Customer>
                <Name>Customer 2 Name</Name>
                <Address>Address Line 2</Address>
              </Customer>
              <CustomerAcct>
                <AcctName>Account Name 2</AcctName>
                <AcctNumber>12345678</AcctNumber>
              </CustomerAcct>
            </Parties>
            <AddlInfo>
              <Info1>Info 1</Info1>
              <Info1>Info 2</Info1>
            </AddlInfo>
          </TransactionDetails>
        </EntryDtls>
      </Entry>
    </Statement>
    <Statement>
      <StmtId>124</StmtId>
      <StmtDate>2013-08-18</StmtDate>
      <AcctNumber>123456780</AcctNumber>
      <Balance>
        <Type>OP</Type>
        <Amount>4.00</Amount>
        <CreditOrDebit>CR</CreditOrDebit>
        <Date>2013-08-15</Date>
      </Balance>
      <Balance>
        <Type>CL</Type>
        <Amount>5.00</Amount>
        <CreditOrDebit>DR</CreditOrDebit>
        <Date>2013-08-16</Date>
      </Balance>
      <Balance>
        <Type>FW</Type>
        <Amount>6.00</Amount>
        <CreditOrDebit>CR</CreditOrDebit>
        <Date>2013-08-17</Date>
      </Balance>
      <Entry>
        <Amount>7777.70</Amount>
        <CreditOrDebit>DR</CreditOrDebit>
        <EntryDtls>
          <TransactionDetails>
            <Parties>
              <Customer>
                <Name>Customer 3 Name</Name>
                <Address>Address Line 3</Address>
              </Customer>
              <CustomerAcct>
                <AcctName>Account Name 3</AcctName>
                <AcctNumber>12345679</AcctNumber>
              </CustomerAcct>
            </Parties>
            <AddlInfo>
              <Info1>Info 1</Info1>
              <Info1>Info 2</Info1>
              <Info1>Info 3</Info1>
            </AddlInfo>
          </TransactionDetails>
        </EntryDtls>
      </Entry>
    </Statement>
  </CustomerRecord>
</Document>
```

Then I have this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:urn="urn-sample">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/urn:Document">
    <Root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement" />
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement">
    <CStatement>
      <CStatementId>
        <xsl:value-of select="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:StmtId" />
      </CStatementId>
      <CStatementDate>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test ="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:StmtDate!=''">
            <xsl:value-of select="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:StmtDate" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Balance[contains('|CL|FW|', concat('|', urn:Type, '|'))]/urn:Date" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </CStatementDate>
      <AccountNumber>
        <xsl:if test="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:AcctNumber!=''">
          <xsl:value-of select ="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:AcctNumber"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </AccountNumber>
      <OpeningBalance>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Balance[contains('|OP|PR|', concat('|', urn:Type, '|'))]/urn:CdtDbtInd='DR'">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Balance[contains('|OP|PR|', concat('|', urn:Type, '|'))]/urn:Amount * -1, '#.00')" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Balance[contains('|OP|PR|', concat('|', urn:Type, '|'))]/urn:Amount, '#.00')" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </OpeningBalance>
      <ClosingBalance>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Balance[contains('|CL|FW|', concat('|', urn:Type, '|'))]/urn:CdtDbtInd='DR'">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Balance[contains('|CL|FW|', concat('|', urn:Type, '|'))]/urn:Amount * -1, '#.00')" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Balance[contains('|CL|FW|', concat('|', urn:Type, '|'))]/urn:Amount, '#.00')" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </ClosingBalance>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Entry" />
    </CStatement>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Entry">
    <StatementLine>
      <DebitOrCredit>
        <xsl:value-of select ="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Entry/urn:CreditOrDebit"/>
      </DebitOrCredit>
      <Amount>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Entry/urn:CreditOrDebit='DR'">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Entry/urn:Amount * -1, '#.00')" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Entry/urn:Amount, '#.00')" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </Amount>
      <CustomerName>
        <xsl:value-of select="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Entry/urn:EntryDtls/urn:TransactionDetails/urn:Parties/urn:Customer/urn:Name" />
        <!--NtryDtls/TransactionDetails/Parties/Dbtr/Nm-->
      </CustomerName>
      <CustomerBankAccount>
        <xsl:value-of select="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:Entry/urn:EntryDtls/urn:TransactionDetails/urn:Parties/urn:CustomerAcct/urn:AcctNumber" />
      </CustomerBankAccount>
      <Description>


      </Description>
    </StatementLine>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That should have this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root> <!--should have no attribute-->
  <CStatement>
    <CStatementId>123</CStatementId>
    <CStatementDate>2013-08-16</CStatementDate>
    <AccountNumber>123456789</AccountNumber>
    <OpeningBalance>-1.00</OpeningBalance>
    <ClosingBalance>2.00</ClosingBalance>
    <CStatementLine>
      <DebitOrCredit>DR</DebitOrCredit>
      <Amount>-7778.70</Amount>
      <CustomerName>Customer 1 Name</CustomerName>
      <CustomerBankAccount>12345677</CustomerBankAccount>
      <Description></Description>
    </CStatementLine>
    <StatementLine>
      <DebitOrCredit>DR</DebitOrCredit>
      <Amount>5555.70</Amount>
      <CustomerName>Customer 2 Name</CustomerName>
      <CustomerBankAccount>12345678</CustomerBankAccount>
      <Description></Description>
    </StatementLine>
  </CStatement>
  <CStatement>
    <CStatementId>124</CStatementId>
    <CStatementDate>2013-08-18</CStatementDate>
    <AccountNumber>123456780</AccountNumber>
    <OpeningBalance>4.00</OpeningBalance>
    <ClosingBalance>-5.00</ClosingBalance>
    <CStatementLine>
      <DebitOrCredit>DR</DebitOrCredit>
      <Amount>7777.70</Amount>
      <CustomerName>Customer 3 Name</CustomerName>
      <CustomerBankAccount>12345679</CustomerBankAccount>
      <Description></Description>
    </CStatementLine>
  </CStatement>
</Root>
```

I have two problem with my XSLT:
1 It is only getting the first value of Statement or StatementLines like this:

```
<Root xmlns:urn="urn-sample">
  <CStatement>
    <CStatementId>123</CStatementId>
    <CStatementDate>2013-08-16</CStatementDate>
    <AccountNumber>123456789</AccountNumber>
    <OpeningBalance>1.00</OpeningBalance>
    <ClosingBalance>2.00</ClosingBalance>
    <StatementLine>
      <DebitOrCredit>DR</DebitOrCredit>
      <Amount>-7778.70</Amount>
      <CustomerName>Customer 1 Name</CustomerName>
      <CustomerBankAccount>12345677</CustomerBankAccount>
      <Description />
    </StatementLine>
    <StatementLine>
      <DebitOrCredit>DR</DebitOrCredit>
      <Amount>-7778.70</Amount>
      <CustomerName>Customer 1 Name</CustomerName>
      <CustomerBankAccount>12345677</CustomerBankAccount>
      <Description />
    </StatementLine>
    <StatementLine>
      <DebitOrCredit>DR</DebitOrCredit>
      <Amount>-7778.70</Amount>
      <CustomerName>Customer 1 Name</CustomerName>
      <CustomerBankAccount>12345677</CustomerBankAccount>
      <Description />
    </StatementLine>
  </CStatement>
  <CStatement>
    <CStatementId>123</CStatementId>
    <CStatementDate>2013-08-16</CStatementDate>
    <AccountNumber>123456789</AccountNumber>
    <OpeningBalance>1.00</OpeningBalance>
    <ClosingBalance>2.00</ClosingBalance>
    <StatementLine>
      <DebitOrCredit>DR</DebitOrCredit>
      <Amount>-7778.70</Amount>
      <CustomerName>Customer 1 Name</CustomerName>
      <CustomerBankAccount>12345677</CustomerBankAccount>
      <Description />
    </StatementLine>
    <StatementLine>
      <DebitOrCredit>DR</DebitOrCredit>
      <Amount>-7778.70</Amount>
      <CustomerName>Customer 1 Name</CustomerName>
      <CustomerBankAccount>12345677</CustomerBankAccount>
      <Description />
    </StatementLine>
    <StatementLine>
      <DebitOrCredit>DR</DebitOrCredit>
      <Amount>-7778.70</Amount>
      <CustomerName>Customer 1 Name</CustomerName>
      <CustomerBankAccount>12345677</CustomerBankAccount>
      <Description />
    </StatementLine>
  </CStatement>
</Root>
```

2 And lastly, not sure how I can use variable or any function to store the value of Description tag with this requirements:

- a. Concatenate strings 'CUST' + Customer/Name + Customer/Address
- b. Concatenate strings 'ACCT' + CustomerAcct/AcctName + > CustomerAcct/AcctNumber
- c. Concatenate what ever values there is under AddlInfo/Info1
- etc
- Concatenate a+b+c .... etc

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks everyone

BTW I need it on XSLT 1.0

Comment: Please reduce all you code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem. Something like 10 lines each would be ideal. It's likely that in boiling down the problem you'll find the root cause yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic mistake is that you are using absolute paths instead of relative ones. Compare the results of these two **minimized** stylesheets:

**XSLT 1.0 (absolute)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:urn="urn-sample">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/urn:Document">
    <Root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement" />
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement">
    <CStatement>
        <CStatementId>
            <xsl:value-of select="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:StmtId" />
        </CStatementId>
    </CStatement>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 1.0 (relative)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:urn="urn-sample"
exclude-result-prefixes="urn">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/urn:Document">
    <Root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement" />
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="urn:Statement">
    <CStatement>
        <CStatementId>
            <xsl:value-of select="urn:StmtId" />
        </CStatementId>
    </CStatement>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the first example, the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/urn:Document/urn:CustomerRecord/urn:Statement/urn:StmtId" />
```

starts from the root and always gets the Id value of the **first** statement, no matter which statement is being currently processed by the loop.

Comment: That is exactly what im looking for.. Now any idea on the second one how to go about it?

Comment: @zyberjock I suggest you post a separate question, as these two are unrelated. Stack Overflow is a public resource - keeping it down to one issue per question helps the readers browsing it to find solutions to their own problems.

Comment: ok thanks, asked another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052304/concatenate-strings-including-repeating-tag